# How will Unity games work on Chrome now that NPAPI is disabled?

Tags: unity, plugin, chrome

[As expected](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation), this September Google disabled NPAPI in Chrome, which Unity Web Player relies on. As far as I know, Chrome now has its own API plugin API.

Will the Web Player returning to Chrome without NPAPI?

If not, what is Unity's future on Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity detailed their plans in [this blog post](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/28/web-publishing-following-chrome-npapi-deprecation/). Unity plans to target the WebGL platform, and recommends that new web games start with Unity 5 WebGL as the default target.

The Web Player will remain supported "as long as it's useful for developers", as NPAPI still works in other major browsers.

Comment: WebGL target is slow to build, has some porting issues, and takes more traffic, but overall is good